# Simplify ASP.Net StreamWriter for appendtext to file

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

Is there anyway to simplify this code so there aren't so many redundant `w = File.AppendText(filePath)` and `w.flush()` and `w.close()` in each if statement?

Anything else I have tried ends up locking the file, and crashing the site because to text file is in use by another process.

```
Public filePath As String = "c:\inetpub\logs\login.txt"
Public w As StreamWriter

Protected Sub LoginUser_LoginError(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles LoginUser.LoginError

    Dim UserName As TextBox = DirectCast(LoginUser.FindControl("UserName"), TextBox)

    Dim CurrentUser As MembershipUser = Membership.GetUser(LoginUser.UserName)

    Dim logLoginError As New Thread(
        Sub()
            If (CurrentUser IsNot Nothing) Then

                If (CurrentUser.IsLockedOut = True) Then
                    w = File.AppendText(filePath)
                    w.WriteLine(CurrentUser.ToString & "'s (" & IPAddress & ") account is locked out - " & DateAndTime.Now)
                    w.Flush()
                    w.Close()
                ElseIf (CurrentUser.IsApproved = False) Then
                    w = File.AppendText(filePath)
                    w.WriteLine(CurrentUser.ToString & " (" & IPAddress & ") is attempting to login, but the account is disabled - " & DateAndTime.Now)
                    w.Flush()
                    w.Close()
                Else
                    w = File.AppendText(filePath)
                    w.WriteLine(CurrentUser.ToString & "'s (" & IPAddress & ") login credentials failed - " & DateAndTime.Now)
                    w.Flush()
                    w.Close()
                End If

            Else
                w = File.AppendText(filePath)
                w.WriteLine("Unknown user " & UserName.Text & " (" & IPAddress & ") attempting to login - " & DateAndTime.Now)
                w.Flush()
                w.Close()
            End If
        End Sub
    )
    logLoginError.Start()

End Sub
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Careful with naming.

`UserName` is an identifier for a `TextBox`, but it's named like a `String` (which *contains* a user's name).

I'd declare and assign `UserName` like this:

```
Dim UserName As String = DirectCast(LoginUser.FindControl("UserName"), TextBox).Text
```

And now the rest of the code can refer to a *string* that represents a *user's name* without any further conversions.

---

`logLoginError` is an identifier for a `Thread`, but it's named like a `Task` (which *runs* on a thread).

`loggerThread` would be a more accurate name for it.

---

This code:

```
w.WriteLine(CurrentUser.ToString & "'s (" & IPAddress & ") account is locked out - " & DateAndTime.Now)
```

Is using way more `String` instances than you'd think:

- CurrentUser.ToString()
- "'s ("
- IPAddress
- ") account is locked out - "
- DateAndTime.Now[.ToString]

And also:

- The string resulting from `CurrentUser.ToString() & "'s ("`
- The string resulting from `CurrentUser.ToString() & "'s (" & IPAdress`
- The string resulting from `CurrentUser.ToString() & "'s (" & IPAdress & ") account is locked out - "`
- The string resulting from `CurrentUser.ToString() & "'s (" & IPAdress & ") account is locked out - " & DateAndTime.Now`

Are you sure `DateAndTime` isn't supposed to be `DateTime`? Also there's a typo in `IPAdress`, should be `IPAddress`.

To fix the number of `String` objects being created, you can use `String.Format` instead of inline concatenations - remember that `String` is an *immutable class*, "appending to it" doesn't *really* append anything, it just creates a new instance.

This would be cleaner and more efficient (multiline to avoid horizontal scrolling):

```
w.WriteLine(String.Format("{0}'s ({1}) account is locked out - {2}", 
                          CurrentUser.ToString, IPAddress, DateAndTime.Now))
```

Comment: String.Format reminds me of Ruby. Shiny.

Answer (score 3):

What you could do is just move that outside of the if statement like this

```
Dim logLoginError As New Thread(
    Sub()
        w = File.AppendText(filePath)
        If (CurrentUser IsNot Nothing) Then
            If (CurrentUser.IsLockedOut = True) Then
                w.WriteLine(CurrentUser.ToString & "'s (" & IPAddress & ") account is locked out - " & DateAndTime.Now)
            ElseIf (CurrentUser.IsApproved = False) Then
                w.WriteLine(CurrentUser.ToString & " (" & IPAddress & ") is attempting to login, but the account is disabled - " & DateAndTime.Now)
            Else
                w.WriteLine(CurrentUser.ToString & "'s (" & IPAddress & ") login credentials failed - " & DateAndTime.Now)
            End If
        Else
            w.WriteLine("Unknown user " & UserName.Text & " (" & IPAddress & ") attempting to login - " & DateAndTime.Now)
        End If
        w.Flush()
        w.Close()
    End Sub
)
```

No matter what you do inside the if blocks you want `w` flushed and closed  so do it outside of the if statement

---

The next thing that you should do is change the Conditionals to look like this:

```
If (CurrentUser.IsLockedOut) Then
```

And

```
ElseIf Not(CurrentUser.IsApproved) Then
```

And you might want to flip flop around the outside if Statement so that it is based on a positive conditional as well

```
Dim logLoginError As New Thread(
    Sub()
        w = File.AppendText(filePath)
        If (CurrentUser Is Nothing) Then
            w.WriteLine("Unknown user " & UserName.Text & " (" & IPAddress & ") attempting to login - " & DateAndTime.Now)
        Else
            If (CurrentUser.IsLockedOut) Then
                w.WriteLine(CurrentUser.ToString() & "'s (" & IPAddress & ") account is locked out - " & DateAndTime.Now)
            ElseIf Not(CurrentUser.IsApproved) Then
                w.WriteLine(CurrentUser.ToString() & " (" & IPAddress & ") is attempting to login, but the account is disabled - " & DateAndTime.Now)
            Else
                w.WriteLine(CurrentUser.ToString() & "'s (" & IPAddress & ") login credentials failed - " & DateAndTime.Now)
            End If
        End If
        w.Flush()
        w.Close()
    End Sub
)
```

This makes the code a whole lot cleaner and less redundant.

---

You call `CurrentUser.ToString`  and it should be `CurrentUser.ToString()`

---

Answer (score 3):

A bit similar to other response but you could separate the logic into two section. One that gets the message and the other that writes the message. If you remove concatenation, you can easily put your error message in the resource file. If you change your code a bit you could even move the String.Format to a single place.

```
Dim message As String = ""

If (CurrentUser IsNot Nothing) Then

    If (CurrentUser.IsLockedOut = True) Then
        message = String.Format("{0}'s ({1}) account is locked out - {2}", CurrentUser.ToString, IPAddress, DateAndTime.Now)
    ElseIf (CurrentUser.IsApproved = False) Then
        message = String.Format("{0} ({1}) is attempting to login, but the account is disabled - {2}", CurrentUser.ToString, IPAddress, DateAndTime.Now)
    Else
        message = String.Format("{0}'s ({1}) login credentials failed - {2}", CurrentUser.ToString, IPAddress, DateAndTime.Now)
    End If

Else
    message = String.Format("Unknown user {0} ({1}) attempting to login - {2}", UserName.Text, IPAddress, DateAndTime.Now)
End If

w = File.AppendText(filePath)
w.WriteLine(message)
w.Flush()
w.Close()
```

**Note:** By separating the logic, you can put them in two different function `GetMessage` and `WriteMessage`.